# SMTP configuration in web.config

Tags: .net, smtp, web-config

My web app can no longer connect to my mail service because they have change the connecting setting from using the Username & Password Authentication to IP based authentication. Im fairly new to this field so I have a hard time trying to configure how to change it.

Below is my connection setting in web.config. I hide my username, password and smtp address for privacy.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    ....
    <add key="smtp" value="****.****.gov.my" />  
    <add key="portnumber" value="25" />  
    <add key="username" value="*****@****.gov.my" />  
    <add key="password" value="****" />  
    <add key="IsSSL" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
    ...
</configuration>
```

How do I change this setting inside web.config to IP based authentication-style? It is even possible to do it in web.config?

To successfully connect back with my mail service provider

Comment: Please add more details. What do you mean when you say "they have changed"? Are you talking about some specific software? If yes, which?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can authenticate using IP, probably you will have to check [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/basicauthentication) for that. You can define unique IP [security restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/add).